# Numba Seg fault with blender

Tags: scripting, gpu, cuda

I'm looking to integrate Numba into my Blender addons. However, I've run into a weird problem. So, I have a simple file

```
from numba import cuda
import numpy
import time
print(cuda.gpus)
import math

@cuda.jit
def f(io_array, main_array):
    tx = cuda.threadIdx.x
    ty = cuda.blockIdx.x
    bw = cuda.blockDim.x
    pos = tx + ty * bw
    if pos < io_array.size:
        io_array[pos] *= 2
        io_array[pos] += main_array[pos]

# Host code 
data = numpy.arange(2560000)
data2 = numpy.arange(2560000)
threadsperblock = 256
blockspergrid = math.ceil(data.shape[0] / threadsperblock)
st = time.time()
f[blockspergrid, threadsperblock](data, data2)
et = time.time()
print("Total time taken ", et - st)
for i in range(10):
    print(data[i])

print(data[255999])
print(data[255998])
```

It works fine when I run it from my system python or blender python interpreter. But it throws a Seg fault when running from Blender. I don't understand if I can run it successfully from the Blender python interpreter, then why does Blender throw a Seg Fault?

Output :

```
Read prefs: /home/sourav/.config/blender/3.0/config/userpref.blend
<Managed Device 0>
Writing: /tmp/blender.crash.txt
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Content of /tmp/blender.crash.txt

```
# Blender 3.0.0, Commit date: 2021-12-02 18:35, Hash f1cca3055776

# backtrace
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(BLI_system_backtrace+0x20) [0xb0b3460]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender() [0x10babdb]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x42520) [0x7ff5d341a520]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/3.0/python/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0x10531) [0x7ff59ebc3531]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.8(+0x77ec) [0x7ff5cf8d77ec]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.8(+0x8050) [0x7ff5cf8d8050]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/3.0/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/llvmlite/binding/libllvmlite.so(+0x5d0de4) [0x7ff597b50de4]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/3.0/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/llvmlite/binding/libllvmlite.so(+0x60bda1) [0x7ff597b8bda1]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/3.0/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/llvmlite/binding/libllvmlite.so(+0x606908) [0x7ff597b86908]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/3.0/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/llvmlite/binding/libllvmlite.so(LLVMPY_FinalizeObject+0x27) [0x7ff597b506f5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.8(+0x7e2e) [0x7ff5cf8d7e2e]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.8(+0x4493) [0x7ff5cf8d4493]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/3.0/python/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0x129d6) [0x7ff59ebc59d6]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/3.0/python/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0xbd3a) [0x7ff59ebbed3a]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyObject_Call+0x5c) [0x9c3306c]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x4199) [0x10b2389]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender() [0x9ce0c84]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyFunction_Vectorcall+0x9a) [0x9c3321a]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyObject_FastCallDictTstate+0x53) [0x9c33643]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyObject_Call_Prepend+0xe4) [0x9c33904]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender() [0x9c94649]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyObject_MakeTpCall+0x90) [0x9c334c0]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x8f40) [0x10b7130]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender() [0x10ad28b]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(PyVectorcall_Call+0x5f) [0x9c32f1f]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x4199) [0x10b2389]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender() [0x9ce0c84]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyFunction_Vectorcall+0x9a) [0x9c3321a]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x678a) [0x10b497a]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender() [0x10ad28b]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x678a) [0x10b497a]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender() [0x10ad28b]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x678a) [0x10b497a]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender() [0x10ad28b]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x678a) [0x10b497a]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender() [0x10ad28b]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x661d) [0x10b480d]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender() [0x10ad28b]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(PyVectorcall_Call+0x5f) [0x9c32f1f]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x4199) [0x10b2389]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender() [0x9ce0c84]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyFunction_Vectorcall+0x9a) [0x9c3321a]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x678a) [0x10b497a]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender() [0x10ad28b]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(PyVectorcall_Call+0x5f) [0x9c32f1f]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x4199) [0x10b2389]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender() [0x9ce0c84]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyFunction_Vectorcall+0x9a) [0x9c3321a]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x678a) [0x10b497a]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender() [0x10ad28b]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender() [0x9c35e98]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x661d) [0x10b480d]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender() [0x9ce0c84]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyFunction_Vectorcall+0x9a) [0x9c3321a]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyObject_FastCallDictTstate+0x53) [0x9c33643]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyObject_Call_Prepend+0xe4) [0x9c33904]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender() [0x9c948f2]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender() [0x9c8a93a]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyObject_MakeTpCall+0x90) [0x9c334c0]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x8f40) [0x10b7130]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender() [0x10ad28b]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x661d) [0x10b480d]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender() [0x9ce0c84]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyFunction_Vectorcall+0x9a) [0x9c3321a]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender() [0x9c33b98]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs+0xa2) [0x9c33ff2]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyObject_GenericGetAttrWithDict+0x1c6) [0x9c76c86]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x3aac) [0x10b1c9c]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender() [0x10ad28b]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender() [0x9c3bd83]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyObject_GenericGetAttrWithDict+0x7f) [0x9c76b3f]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x3aac) [0x10b1c9c]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender() [0x9ce0c84]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyFunction_Vectorcall+0x9a) [0x9c3321a]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyObject_FastCallDictTstate+0xca) [0x9c336ba]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyObject_Call_Prepend+0xe4) [0x9c33904]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender() [0x9c948f2]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender() [0x9c8a93a]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyObject_Call+0x5c) [0x9c3306c]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x4199) [0x10b2389]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender() [0x9ce0c84]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyFunction_Vectorcall+0x9a) [0x9c3321a]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x59cc) [0x10b3bbc]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender() [0x9ce0c84]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyFunction_Vectorcall+0x9a) [0x9c3321a]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x59cc) [0x10b3bbc]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender() [0x9ce0c84]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName+0x4e) [0x9ce0fce]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x3e) [0x9ce101e]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(PyEval_EvalCode+0x1b) [0x9ce104b]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender() [0x9d1b9c5]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(PyRun_FileExFlags+0xad) [0x9d1dafd]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender() [0x1bf93ff]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender() [0x10b8e5a]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(BLI_args_parse+0xc7) [0xaff6937]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender(main+0x2d5) [0xfa3b75]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x29d90) [0x7ff5d3401d90]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0x80) [0x7ff5d3401e40]
/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/blender() [0x10b753c]

# Python backtrace
  File "/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/3.0/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/llvmlite/binding/ffi.py", line 151 in __call__
  File "/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/3.0/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/llvmlite/binding/executionengine.py", line 92 in finalize_object
  File "/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/3.0/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/codegen.py", line 1060 in wrapper
  File "/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/3.0/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/codegen.py", line 999 in _finalize_specific
  File "/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/3.0/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/codegen.py", line 797 in _finalize_final_module
  File "/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/3.0/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/codegen.py", line 765 in finalize
  File "/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/3.0/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/runtime/nrtdynmod.py", line 213 in compile_nrt_functions
  File "/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/3.0/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/runtime/nrt.py", line 41 in initialize
  File "/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/3.0/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_lock.py", line 35 in _acquire_compile_lock
  File "/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/3.0/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/cpu.py", line 59 in init
  File "/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/3.0/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_lock.py", line 35 in _acquire_compile_lock
  File "/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/3.0/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/base.py", line 257 in __init__
  File "/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/3.0/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/cpu.py", line 40 in __init__
  File "/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/3.0/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/registry.py", line 31 in _toplevel_target_context
  File "/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/3.0/python/lib/python3.9/functools.py", line 969 in __get__
  File "/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/3.0/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/registry.py", line 47 in target_context
  File "/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/3.0/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 824 in __init__
  File "/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/3.0/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/decorators.py", line 208 in wrapper
  File "/home/pc/blender-3.0.0/3.0/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/decorators.py", line 179 in jit
  File "/home/pc/tmp/gpu2.py", line 10 in <module>
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you manage to solve it? To add I'm also getting this printout in the console: `../src/intel/isl/isl.c:2216: FINISHME: ../src/intel/isl/isl.c:isl_surf_supports_ccs: CCS for 3D textures is disabled, but a workaround is available.`

minimal example: `from numba import jit \n @jit \n def f(): \n return 1`

Comment: update: the printout I mentioned happens at startup, so probably unrelated to the crash